# Python Requests Recreate Post Request with Cookies

Tags: python, cookies, request

So I was looking at my chrome console for a post request that I was making, and there is a 'cookie' value in the header file that has this data:

strTradeLastInventoryContext=730_2; bCompletedTradeOfferTutorial=true; steamMachineAuth76561198052177472=3167F37117************B82C2E; steamMachineAuth76561198189250810=E292770040E************B5F97703126DE48E; rgDiscussionPrefs=%7B%22cTopicRepliesPerPage%******%7D; sessionid=053257f1102e4967e2527ced; steamCountry=US%7C708d3************e569cc75495; steamLogin=76561198052177472%7C%7C4EC6FBDFA0****************12DE568; steamLoginSecure=765611*********************44BEC4E8BDA86264E; webTradeEligibility=%7B%22allowed%22%3A1%2C%22allowed_at_time%22%3A0%2C%22steamguard_required_days%22%3A15%2C%22sales_this_year%22%3A9%2C%22max_sales_per_year%22%3A200%2C%22forms_request***************cooldown_days%22%3A7%7D; strInventoryLastContext=730_2; recentlyVisitedAppHubs=42700%2C2***********930%2C440; timezoneOffset=-14400,0; __utma=268881843.1147920287.1419547163.1431887507.1431890089.151; __utmb=268881843.0.10.1431890089; __utmc=268881843; __utmz=268881843.1431885538.149.94.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)

I starred out some of the cookie's data so my trade account couldn't be robbed, but you should get the point. How should I go about recreating the cookie? Like should I create a dict with the keys being the values before the '=' in the cookie and the value being what comes after the '=' sign? Sorry if the question is unclear, I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Any help would be great!

Ex. cookie = {strTradeLastInventoryContext: 730_2, ...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are really two options here.

---

If you happen to have the exact `Cookie` header you want to reproduce exactly as one big string (e.g., to have a `requests`-driven job take over a session you created in a browser, manually or using `selenium` or whatever), you can just pass that as an arbitrary header named `Cookie` instead of figuring out how to break it apart just so `requests` can (hopefully) reassemble the same header you wanted.

---

If, on the other hand, you need to create parts of it dynamically, then yes, you will want to do what you're doing—pull it apart to build a dict named `cookie`, then use it with `requests.get(url, cookies=cookie)`, or `req.cookies.update(cookie)` or similar (if you're using sessions and prepared requests). Then you can easily modify the dict before sending it.

But the easiest way to do that is not to pull the cookie apart manually. I'm pretty sure the WebKit Developer Tools have a way to do that for you directly within Chrome. Or, if not, you can just copy the cookie as a string and then use the [`http.cookies`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/http.cookies.html) module (called [`cookie`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cookie.html) in Python 2.x), like this:

```
cookie = http.cookies.BaseCookie(cookie_string)
```

---

Also, note that in many cases, you really don't even need to do this. If you can drive the login and navigation directly from `requests` instead of starting off in Chrome, it should end up with the full set of cookies it needs in each request. You may need to use a [`Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/), but that's as hard as it gets.

Comment: Yeah, what I've tried to do is just paste in the long cookie under the Cookie tag in the header, but I'm still getting a 401 error. I may have messed up something else in one of the form files. Btw, do you know of a good way to debug post requests? It's not all that helpful to just know that it failed. Thanks!

Comment: @FaTalCubez: Well, you've got the full headers and body that `requests` sent (to compare to the one Chrome sent), and the body of the 401 error, both of which are generally very helpful in debugging. But that isn't always sufficient—especially for for debugging login-related issues, where the server devs are usually more inclined to go out of their way to make it _harder_ for you than _easier_, for (real or misplaced) security reasons.

Comment: Does it matter what order the keys are in for the json file that I will be sending? Because pro-grammatically they are in order, but when I debug the request they get moved around.

Comment: @FaTalCubez: It _shouldn't_ matter. JSON objects, like Python dicts, are defined as not having any inherent order. However, if you're dealing with a badly-written server that's only tested against one specific JS front end, they may assume an order even though they're not supposed to, so it's not impossible that it would matter. You can test that pretty easily by just composing the string manually and sending it as a string rather than using `json.dumps` or letting `requests` jsonify a dict for you.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the requests documentation for [cookies.](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies)
You are right in that the cookie value is passed to the get call as a dictionary key/value.

```
cookies = {'cookie_key': 'somelongstring'}
requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)
```